# How to put three different paragraphs vertically next to each other in a single list?

Tags: html, css

[image: A list element]
  --

Html:

```
    </li>`<ul id="wrapper"> 
    <li>
        <a href="#"> Catelyn</a>
    </li>`
```

Css:

```
li {
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
background: #673ab7;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
border-radius: 2px;
text-align: center;}

ul#wrapper {
list-style: none;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 100px;}

a {

font-size: 24px;
color: cyan;
line-height: 100px;
font-family: monospace;
text-decoration: none;}
```

I want to put one paragraph on top of the "Catelyn" text. One on the bottom of the "Catelyn" text. I want to use paragraph element for this purpose. I want to add two paragraph and do it like this:

[image: Desired]

I could not figure out how to do it. I tried to put `<p> TRY123 </p>` before and after `<a href="#"> Catelyn</a>` like this: `<p> TRY123 </p> <a href="#"> Catelyn</a> <p> TRY123 </p>` but this happens: (and i tried many things.)

[image: What?]

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the `<a>` tag `display: block;` by default it is set to `display: inline`.

Also, make sure your `<ul>`'s are closed.

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type:none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: purple;
}
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>First paragraph</p>
    <a href="">Catelyn</a>
    <p>Second paragraph</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What a good answer! You're awesome. Thank you. @Hastig Zusammenstellen